# Why Ropsten Testnet has Total Ether Supply < the biggest ether holder balance?

Tags: ether, ropsten, web3.py

Let's see two below image that I cropped them from ropsten.etherscan.io.
Can someone tell me why Total Ether Supply < the first address balance?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Where exactly did you get that first image from?

Comment: @shane https://ropsten.etherscan.io/stat/supply